# is_numeric or a numeric preg_match?

Tags: php, security

I read on a forum that you can't completely trust *is_numeric().* It lets through "0xFF" for example which is an allowed hexadecimal...

So my question is can you trick *is_numeric*? Will I need to use a regex to do it correctly?

Answer (score 12):

Here is what [is_numeric()](http://php.net/is_numeric) considers to be a numeric string:

> Numeric strings consist of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value. Hexadecimal notation (0xFF) is allowed too but only without sign, decimal and exponential part.

If you only want to check if a string consists of decimal digits 0-9, you could use [ctype_digit()](http://php.net/ctype_digit).

Comment: It's kind of comical that VB.NET devs were scolded for using ctypes because .NET allowed for proper data type checking but in PHP it's the preferred way.

Answer (score 2):

One can also check using [`ctype_digit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) to check if its a true number.

Answer (score 0):

Regex would obviously be your better option, however it does come with an overhead. So it really depends on your situation and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is it for validating user input? Then the overhead of using a regexp or asserting it doesn't contain an "x" and is_numeric() wouldn't be too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check that something is an integer, try this:

```
function isInteger($value){
    return (is_numeric($value) ? intval($value) == $value : false);
}
```

If you want to check for floats too then this won't work obviously :)

Comment: Why not simply `return is_numeric( $value ) && intval( $value ) == $value`? Easier to read.